# How get the sum of all the checkbox values of checked items

Tags: javascript

```js
let addonCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-checkbox")
let priceSection = document.getElementById("priceSection")
let customProductPricing = document.getElementById("customProductPricing")

for (let i = 0; i < addonCheckboxes.length; i++) {
  addonCheckboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (addonCheckboxes[i].checked != false) {
      priceSection.textContent = parseInt(customProductPricing) + parseInt(addonCheckboxes[i].getAttribute("price"));
    } else {
      priceSection.textContent = parseInt(customProductPricing)
    }
  })

}
```

```html
<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" price="150"></input>
<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" price="150"></input>
<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" price="150"></input>

<div id="priceSection">
  </id>

  <div id="customProductPricing">"150"</div>
```

I want to get the total of all the checkboxes if they are all checked. So far it gives only one value. And need to deduct the prices if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: What is `customProductPricing`

Comment: @phuzi forgot to add that, it is another string value that comes from a different location. updated the code

Comment: There is no `price` attribute in HTML, which renders your document invalid HTML. If you need to define your own attributes, those **must be pre-fixed with `data-`**. Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes . Next, there is an unclosed `div` in your markup, as well as a useless and non-existent closing tag `</id>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one has fixed all the errors you made in your markup, and simplified the code by alot.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('priceSection');

const totalPrice = () => [...document.querySelectorAll('#prices input[type=checkbox]:checked')]
  .reduce((acc, {
    dataset: {
      price
    }
  }) => acc + +price, 0);

document.getElementById('prices').addEventListener('change', () => output.textContent = totalPrice());
```

```html
<div id="prices">
  <input type="checkbox" data-price="10" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-price="20" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-price="30" />
</div>
<div id="priceSection"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting instead of summing. When you are iterating through an array of checkboxes and you find that more than one is checked your function fails.
You should firstly count the sum of checked checkboxes and then send it to `priceSection`, and when your sum is equal to zero you should set it `parseInt(customProductPricing)` like you did in else.

Answer (score 0):

When the change event of the `<input>` elements is triggered, the `update()` method is called and the values in the page are collected and printed on the page. I don't understand the issue of lowering the price if the checkbox is not selected. Update the `update()` method to subtract unselected values from the total using the following approach; Add an `else` statement to the `if` block.

```js
(function() {
  let addonCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-checkbox");
  
  function update()
  {
    let total = parseInt(document.getElementById("customProductPricing").textContent);
    
    for(let i = 0 ; i < addonCheckboxes.length ; ++i)
      if(addonCheckboxes[i].checked == true)
        total += parseInt(addonCheckboxes[i].value);
        
    document.getElementById("priceSection").innerHTML = "Result: " + total;
  }

  for(let i = 0 ; i < addonCheckboxes.length ; ++i)
    addonCheckboxes[i].addEventListener("change", update);
})();
```

```html
<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="10"/>
<label>10</label>

<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="20"/>
<label>20<label>

<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="30"/>
<label>30<label>

<!-- Static Value -->
<div id="customProductPricing">40</div>

<br><div id="priceSection" style="color: red;">Result: </div>
```

Comment: Please don't suggest the use of inline event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sercan has mentioned... I am also not sure about the issue of loweing the sum but I've whipped up something for you.

Hopefully it'll lead you to what you want to achieve.

```js
let addonCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-checkbox")
let priceSection = document.getElementById("priceSection")
let customProductPricing = document.getElementById("customProductPricing");

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-checkbox");

function sum(){
   var total = 0;
   for(let x = 0; x < checkboxes.length; x++){
      let price = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
      if(price[0].checked){
        total = total + Number(price[0].dataset.price);
      }
   }
   console.log('Sum = ' + total)
}
```

```html
<input class="custom-checkbox 0" onclick="sum()" type="checkbox" data-price="150"></input>
<input class="custom-checkbox 1" onclick="sum()" type="checkbox" data-price="150"></input>
<input class="custom-checkbox 2" onclick="sum()" type="checkbox" data-price="150"></input>

<div id="priceSection"></id>

<div id="customProductPricing">"150"</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using data set you can access price

```js
let addonCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-checkbox")
let priceSection = document.getElementById("priceSection")
let customProductPricing = document.getElementById("customProductPricing")
let sum = 0
for (let i = 0; i < addonCheckboxes.length; i++) {
  addonCheckboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {

    console.log(e.target.dataset.price)
    
    if (addonCheckboxes[i].checked != false) {
      
      sum = sum +Number(e.target.dataset.price) 
    } else {
      sum =  sum -Number(e.target.dataset.price) 
    }
    
    customProductPricing.innerHTML = sum
    
  })

}
```

```html
<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-price="150"></input>
<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-price="150"></input>
<input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-price="150"></input>

<div id="priceSection">
  </id>

  <div id="customProductPricing">"150"</div>
```